# message that 'features.h' file not found and 'libioP.h' file not found

Tags: c, qt, mingw

so.. there is code. explain the code line by line. and i have the message that 'features.h' file not found and 'libioP.h' file not found. how i can fix it? compiler minGW in QT

```
#include <features.h>
#undef __GLIBC_USE_DEPRECATED_SCANF
#define __GLIBC_USE_DEPRECATED_SCANF 1
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libioP.h>
/* Read formatted input from stdin according to the format string FORMAT. */
/* VARARGS1 */
int
__scanf (const char *format, ...)
{
va_list arg;
int done;
va_start (arg, format);
done = __vfscanf_internal (stdin, format, arg, 0);
va_end (arg);
return done;
}
ldbl_strong_alias (__scanf, scanf)
```

Comment: What is the exact error and wat is configuration? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515168

Comment: error 1: 'features.h' file not found. error 2: 'libioP.h' file not found. I have Win 10 x64 but compiler minGW 32 bit. I work in QT. Programming language is C

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install libraries to support GCC. The solution varies depending on what OS you use.

If you are using Ubuntu, use:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

For other OS, you can search install build-essential + your OS for further information

Build-essential s a collection of essential libraries for the compiler, the .h files you posted belong to one of these libraries. Did you check the packages when install the MinGW? It should be in Basic Setup like this

[image]

Those libraries which name includes gcc or lib are very likely needed in your current and future projects, you can reinstall the MinGW to download these packages.

Comment: I have Win10. I didnt hear about build-essential. what is it and how I can install it?

Comment: It's a collection of essential libraries for the compiler, the .h files you posted belong to one of these libraries. Did you check the packages when install the MinGW? It should be in Basic Setup like this

Comment: Yes I check the packages. I found only features.h but I cant found libioP.h there. Where I can install libioP.h?